# UICollectionView cells not updating after reload

Tags: uicollectionview

```
 self.filterCollectionView.reloadData()
```

After calling reload data the visible cell's cellforItem is called but my cell values are not updating until I scroll back and forth

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.selected = false
        cell.alpha = 1.0
        for each in cell.contentView.subviews{
            each.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 40))
        title.text = filterArray[indexPath.row]
        title.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        title.textAlignment = .Center
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

        cell.contentView.addSubview(title)
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: What's your code in cellForItemAtIndexPath? Is `self.filterCollectionView.reloadData()` called in main thread? Where?

Comment: @Larme its in main only